# How can I disable Kohana 3.3 error message?

Tags: exception, kohana

I'm using the Kohana 3.3 framework. I'm trying to disable the error messages for production machine.

The error message looks like :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY2yD.png

In the production machine, I want to disable the debug tracking and the error message. I tried lots of ways but it didn't work.

So, my question is:
How can I disable the exception error messages ? 
Thanks.

Comment: You should create a custom error message pages

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in the bootstrap file:

`Kohana::init(array('errors' => FALSE));`

Kohana should now stop generating exceptions when an error happens.

Note:

This is highly discouraged by the Kohana development team and you should just catch the exceptions in a meaningfull way.

Comment: that does not resolve the problem. When database exceptions throw out, I can see the error page too. Should I add a try catch to catch the execute() index.php ? or do you have other good methods? Thanks.

Comment: No, that's not recommended either. If it is a database exception handle (log error, generate error message and maybe throw a new exception) it wherever it is thrown and show a nice error page to your client. Here a link with how you set up custom error pages: http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/errors

Answer (score 0):

You should leave errors on so you can use Kohana to catch your exceptions.

So if we do it this way, there shouldn't ever be uncaught exceptions.

You can change the way Kohana manages http exceptions by setting

```
Kohana::$environment = Kohana::DEVELOPMENT
```

in bootstrap.php